# Running Calculations Against Cypher Subqueries

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Suppose I have the following Graph setup:

```
CREATE (john:Person {name: 'John Doe'}), (jane:Person {name: 'Jane Doe'}), (bob:Person {name: 'Bob Doe'})
CREATE (reading:Hobby {name: 'Reading'}), (sports:Hobby {name: 'Sports'}), (music:Hobby {name: 'Music'})
MERGE (john)-[:LIKES {intensity: 25}]->(reading)
MERGE (john)-[:LIKES {intensity: 70}]->(sports)
MERGE (john)-[:DISLIKES {intensity: 15}]->(music)
MERGE (jane)-[:LIKES {intensity: 50}]->(reading)
MERGE (jane)-[:DISLIKES {intensity: 40}]->(sports)
MERGE (jane)-[:LIKES {intensity: 20}]->(music)
MERGE (bob)-[:DISLIKES {intensity: 35}]->(reading)
MERGE (bob)-[:LIKES {intensity: 50}]->(sports)
MERGE (bob)-[:LIKES {intensity: 25}]->(music)
```

Each Person may LIKE or DISLIKE a given Hobby with a certain arbitrary intensity.

To calculate each Person's mutual "passion" (mutual LIKES or DISLIKES) for any given hobby, I can run the following:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[al]->(h:Hobby)<-[bl]-(b:Person)
WHERE ID(a) < ID(b) AND TYPE(al) = TYPE(bl)
RETURN a.name, b.name, TYPE(al), h.name, (al.intensity + bl.intensity) / 2 AS passion
```

And to calculate each Person's "disdain" for a given Hobby, I can run the inverse:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[al]->(h:Hobby)<-[bl]-(b:Person)
WHERE ID(a) < ID(b) AND TYPE(al) <> TYPE(bl)
RETURN a.name, b.name, h.name, (al.intensity + bl.intensity) / 2 AS disdain
```

**Both calculations return the information in exactly the way that I'm expecting, but I'm having some trouble figuring out the difference between "passion" and "disdain" in a single query to calculate a final "compatibility" rating and sorting the results in descending order.**

What I had attempted was something like this:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[al]->(h:Hobby)<-[bl]-(b:Person)
WHERE ID(a) < ID(b) AND TYPE(al) <> TYPE(bl)
WITH (al.intensity + bl.intensity) / 2 AS disdain
MATCH (a:Person)-[al]->(h:Hobby)<-[bl]-(b:Person)
WHERE ID(a) < ID(b) AND TYPE(al) = TYPE(bl)
WITH a, b, h, disdain, (al.intensity + bl.intensity) / 2 AS passion
RETURN a.name, b.name, h.name, passion, disdain, (passion - disdain) AS compatibility
ORDER BY compatibility DESC
```

But I ended up getting results that were VERY incorrect due to my inexperience with Neo4j and Cypher queries in general.

**I have a feeling that I'll need to use a combination of [COLLECT](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) and [UNWIND](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/) in order to achieve what I want, but I'm unsure of how to approach it, and whether or not I'm even on the right track.**

As a side note, I know that I can probably achieve a simpler result by keeping the relationship limited to LIKES and using a signed integer for intensity (ie: a negative LIKE can denote a DISLIKE), but I would prefer keeping them separated if possible.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**

Using the answer that stdob gave me, I was able to throw in some aggregates and I ended up with the following:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[al]->(h:Hobby)<-[bl]-(b:Person)
WHERE ID(a) < ID(b)
WITH a, al, h, bl, b, (al.intensity + bl.intensity)/2 AS value
WITH a, al, h, bl, b, value,
    CASE WHEN TYPE(al) =  TYPE(bl) THEN value ELSE 0 END AS mutual,
    CASE WHEN TYPE(al) <> TYPE(bl) THEN value ELSE 0 END AS separate
RETURN DISTINCT a.name, SUM(mutual) AS passion, SUM(separate) AS disdain, (SUM(mutual) - SUM(separate)) AS compatibility, b.name
ORDER BY compatibility DESC
```

The output is much more sane and is exactly what I was hoping for:

```
NAME A      PASSION   DISDAIN   COMPATIBILITY  NAME B
"John Doe"  60        50        10             "Bob Doe"
"John Doe"  37        72        -35            "Jane Doe"
"Jane Doe"  22        87        -65            "Bob Doe"
```

Comment: Can you show to us the expected output sorted according the sample data set posted, please? Thanks.

Comment: @BrunoPeres I was able to get it figured out with the answer that stdob provided. I've updated the question with both Cypher Query that worked, as well as the final output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need something like this:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[al]->(h:Hobby)<-[bl]-(b:Person)
WHERE ID(a) < ID(b)
WITH a, al, h, bl, b, (al.intensity + bl.intensity)/2 AS value
WITH a, al, h, bl, b, value,
     CASE WHEN TYPE(al) =  TYPE(bl) THEN value ELSE 0 END AS passion,
     CASE WHEN TYPE(al) <> TYPE(bl) THEN value ELSE 0 END AS disdain
RETURN a.name, b.name, h.name, 
       passion, disdain, 
       ABS(passion - disdain)/2.0 AS compatibility 
ORDER BY compatibility DESC
```

Comment: That got me exactly the head start I needed. Using what you gave me, I was able to modify the query to get exactly the results I was expecting. I'll add it to the question so that I can format it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `UNION` to combine results from the two queries:

```
WHERE ID(a) < ID(b) AND TYPE(al) = TYPE(bl)
RETURN a.name, b.name, "passion" AS intent, h.name, (al.intensity + bl.intensity) / 2 AS metric
UNION
MATCH (a:Person)-[al]->(h:Hobby)<-[bl]-(b:Person)
WHERE ID(a) < ID(b) AND TYPE(al) <> TYPE(bl)
RETURN a.name, b.name, "disdain" AS intent, h.name, (al.intensity + bl.intensity) / 2 AS metric
```

Comment: UNIONs aren't going to work here, unfortunately. I'm looking to order the result set in descending order, which Neo4j doesn't allow post-UNION processing. Additionally, the "metric" column in your case doesn't calculate the difference between the "passion" and "disdain" columns. +1 for the answer, though. I've highlighted the important part in my question for clarity.

Comment: @maiorano84 You may want to take a look at this knowledge base article for [post-union processing](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/post-union-processing/). You'll need APOC for this, however.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my cypher session and solution to the problem you put forth.

My approach presumes that the lack of both LIKE and DISLIKE relationships represents an intensity of zero toward that Hobby.  I also made DISLIKE intensities negative.

Note: it uses APOC functions, so you'll need that installed.

See here: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures

```
neo4j> // Step 1: Get a resultset of hobbies that we care about

        MATCH (h:Hobby)
         WITH h.name AS hobby
        ORDER BY hobby
       RETURN hobby;

+-----------+
| hobby     |
+-----------+
| "Music"   |
| "Reading" |
| "Sports"  |
+-----------+


neo4j> // Step 2: Convert rows of hobbies into a collection of hobbies (row2col)

        MATCH (h:Hobby)
         WITH h.name AS hobby
        ORDER BY hobby
         WITH COLLECT(hobby) AS hobbies
       RETURN hobbies;

+--------------------------------+
| hobbies                        |
+--------------------------------+
| ["Music", "Reading", "Sports"] |
+--------------------------------+


neo4j> // Step 3: With hobbies as "global" state, match with every :Person node

        MATCH (h:Hobby)
         WITH h.name AS hobby
        ORDER BY hobby
         WITH COLLECT(hobby) AS hobbies
        MATCH (person:Person)
       RETURN hobbies, person;

+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| hobbies                        | person                       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| ["Music", "Reading", "Sports"] | (:Person {name: "John Doe"}) |
| ["Music", "Reading", "Sports"] | (:Person {name: "Jane Doe"}) |
| ["Music", "Reading", "Sports"] | (:Person {name: "Bob Doe"})  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+


neo4j> // Step 4: Gather likes and dislikes into maps

        MATCH (h:Hobby)
         WITH h.name AS hobby
        ORDER BY hobby
         WITH COLLECT(hobby) AS hobbies
        MATCH (person:Person)
       OPTIONAL
        MATCH (person)-[LIKES:LIKES]->(h:Hobby)
         WITH hobbies, person, apoc.map.fromLists(COLLECT(h.name), COLLECT(LIKES.intensity)) AS likes
       OPTIONAL
        MATCH (person)-[DISLIKES:DISLIKES]->(h:Hobby)
       RETURN hobbies, person, likes,
              apoc.map.fromLists(COLLECT(h.name), COLLECT(DISLIKES.intensity)) AS dislikes;

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| hobbies                        | person                       | likes                     | dislikes      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ["Music", "Reading", "Sports"] | (:Person {name: "Jane Doe"}) | {Music: 20, Reading: 50}  | {Sports: 40}  |
| ["Music", "Reading", "Sports"] | (:Person {name: "John Doe"}) | {Reading: 25, Sports: 70} | {Music: 15}   |
| ["Music", "Reading", "Sports"] | (:Person {name: "Bob Doe"})  | {Music: 25, Sports: 50}   | {Reading: 35} |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


neo4j> // Step 5: Turn maps into collections (vectors), using hobbies list

        MATCH (h:Hobby)
         WITH h.name AS hobby
        ORDER BY hobby
         WITH COLLECT(hobby) AS hobbies
        MATCH (person:Person)
       OPTIONAL
        MATCH (person)-[LIKES:LIKES]->(h:Hobby)
         WITH hobbies, person, apoc.map.fromLists(COLLECT(h.name), COLLECT(LIKES.intensity)) AS likes
       OPTIONAL
        MATCH (person)-[DISLIKES:DISLIKES]->(h:Hobby)
         WITH hobbies, person, likes,
              apoc.map.fromLists(COLLECT(h.name), COLLECT(DISLIKES.intensity)) AS dislikes
       RETURN person,
              [x IN hobbies | COALESCE(likes[x], 0)] AS likes,
              [x IN hobbies | COALESCE(-dislikes[x], 0)] AS dislikes;

+----------------------------------------------------------+
| person                       | likes       | dislikes    |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| (:Person {name: "Jane Doe"}) | [20, 50, 0] | [0, 0, -40] |
| (:Person {name: "John Doe"}) | [0, 25, 70] | [-15, 0, 0] |
| (:Person {name: "Bob Doe"})  | [25, 0, 50] | [0, -35, 0] |
+----------------------------------------------------------+


neo4j> // Step 6: Map each person against each other

        MATCH (h:Hobby)
         WITH h.name AS hobby
        ORDER BY hobby
         WITH COLLECT(hobby) AS hobbies
        MATCH (person:Person)
       OPTIONAL
        MATCH (person)-[LIKES:LIKES]->(h:Hobby)
         WITH hobbies, person, apoc.map.fromLists(COLLECT(h.name), COLLECT(LIKES.intensity)) AS likes
       OPTIONAL
        MATCH (person)-[DISLIKES:DISLIKES]->(h:Hobby)
         WITH hobbies, person, likes,
              apoc.map.fromLists(COLLECT(h.name), COLLECT(DISLIKES.intensity)) AS dislikes
         WITH person,
              [x IN hobbies | COALESCE(likes[x], 0)] AS likes,
              [x IN hobbies | COALESCE(-dislikes[x], 0)] AS dislikes
         WITH COLLECT({person:person, likes:likes, dislikes:dislikes}) AS rows
       UNWIND rows AS left
       UNWIND rows AS right
         WITH left, right
        WHERE ID(left.person) < ID(right.person)
       RETURN left, right;

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| left                                                                              | right                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {person: (:Person {name: "Jane Doe"}), dislikes: [0, 0, -40], likes: [20, 50, 0]} | {person: (:Person {name: "Bob Doe"}), dislikes: [0, -35, 0], likes: [25, 0, 50]}  |
| {person: (:Person {name: "John Doe"}), dislikes: [-15, 0, 0], likes: [0, 25, 70]} | {person: (:Person {name: "Jane Doe"}), dislikes: [0, 0, -40], likes: [20, 50, 0]} |
| {person: (:Person {name: "John Doe"}), dislikes: [-15, 0, 0], likes: [0, 25, 70]} | {person: (:Person {name: "Bob Doe"}), dislikes: [0, -35, 0], likes: [25, 0, 50]}  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


neo4j> // Step 7: Calculate simple averages

        MATCH (h:Hobby)
         WITH h.name AS hobby
        ORDER BY hobby
         WITH COLLECT(hobby) AS hobbies
        MATCH (person:Person)
       OPTIONAL
        MATCH (person)-[LIKES:LIKES]->(h:Hobby)
         WITH hobbies, person, apoc.map.fromLists(COLLECT(h.name), COLLECT(LIKES.intensity)) AS likes
       OPTIONAL
        MATCH (person)-[DISLIKES:DISLIKES]->(h:Hobby)
         WITH hobbies, person, likes,
              apoc.map.fromLists(COLLECT(h.name), COLLECT(DISLIKES.intensity)) AS dislikes
         WITH person,
              [x IN hobbies | COALESCE(likes[x], 0)] AS likes,
              [x IN hobbies | COALESCE(-dislikes[x], 0)] AS dislikes
         WITH COLLECT({person: person, likes:likes, dislikes:dislikes}) AS coll
       UNWIND coll AS left
       UNWIND coll AS right
         WITH left, right
        WHERE ID(left.person) < ID(right.person)
       RETURN left.person.name,
              right.person.name,
              left.likes,
              right.likes,
              EXTRACT(x IN apoc.coll.zip(left.likes, right.likes)       | (x[0] + x[1]) / 2) AS avg_like,
              left.dislikes,
              right.dislikes,
              EXTRACT(x IN apoc.coll.zip(left.dislikes, right.dislikes) | (x[0] + x[1]) / 2) AS avg_dislike;

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| left.person.name | right.person.name | left.likes  | right.likes | avg_like     | left.dislikes | right.dislikes | avg_dislike   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "Jane Doe"       | "Bob Doe"         | [20, 50, 0] | [25, 0, 50] | [22, 25, 25] | [0, 0, -40]   | [0, -35, 0]    | [0, -17, -20] |
| "John Doe"       | "Jane Doe"        | [0, 25, 70] | [20, 50, 0] | [10, 37, 35] | [-15, 0, 0]   | [0, 0, -40]    | [-7, 0, -20]  |
| "John Doe"       | "Bob Doe"         | [0, 25, 70] | [25, 0, 50] | [12, 12, 60] | [-15, 0, 0]   | [0, -35, 0]    | [-7, -17, 0]  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

neo4j> // Step 8: Try apoc.algo.euclideanSimilarity()

        MATCH (h:Hobby)
         WITH h.name AS hobby
        ORDER BY hobby
         WITH COLLECT(hobby) AS hobbies
        MATCH (person:Person)
       OPTIONAL
        MATCH (person)-[LIKES:LIKES]->(h:Hobby)
         WITH hobbies, person, apoc.map.fromLists(COLLECT(h.name), COLLECT(LIKES.intensity)) AS likes
       OPTIONAL
        MATCH (person)-[DISLIKES:DISLIKES]->(h:Hobby)
         WITH hobbies, person, likes,
              apoc.map.fromLists(COLLECT(h.name), COLLECT(DISLIKES.intensity)) AS dislikes
         WITH person,
              [x IN hobbies | COALESCE(likes[x], 0)] AS likes,
              [x IN hobbies | COALESCE(-dislikes[x], 0)] AS dislikes
         WITH COLLECT({person: person, likes:likes, dislikes:dislikes}) AS coll
       UNWIND coll AS left
       UNWIND coll AS right
         WITH left, right
        WHERE ID(left.person) < ID(right.person)
       RETURN left.person.name,
              right.person.name,
              EXTRACT(x IN apoc.coll.zip(left.likes, right.likes)       | (x[0] + x[1]) / 2) AS avg_like,
              EXTRACT(x IN apoc.coll.zip(left.dislikes, right.dislikes) | (x[0] + x[1]) / 2) AS avg_dislike,
              apoc.algo.euclideanSimilarity(left.likes, right.likes) AS euclidean_like,
              apoc.algo.euclideanSimilarity(left.dislikes, right.dislikes) AS euclidean_dislike;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| left.person.name | right.person.name | avg_like     | avg_dislike   | euclidean_like       | euclidean_dislike    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "John Doe"       | "Jane Doe"        | [10, 37, 35] | [-7, 0, -20]  | 0.012824784198464426 | 0.02287281728431341  |
| "John Doe"       | "Bob Doe"         | [12, 12, 60] | [-7, -17, 0]  | 0.024026799286343117 | 0.025589279178274353 |
| "Jane Doe"       | "Bob Doe"         | [22, 25, 25] | [0, -17, -20] | 0.013910675635706434 | 0.018466972048042936 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


neo4j> // Step 9: Save our similarity calculations (yay, new relationships!)

        MATCH (h:Hobby)
         WITH h.name AS hobby
        ORDER BY hobby
         WITH COLLECT(hobby) AS hobbies
        MATCH (person:Person)
       OPTIONAL
        MATCH (person)-[LIKES:LIKES]->(h:Hobby)
         WITH hobbies, person, apoc.map.fromLists(COLLECT(h.name), COLLECT(LIKES.intensity)) AS likes
       OPTIONAL
        MATCH (person)-[DISLIKES:DISLIKES]->(h:Hobby)
         WITH hobbies, person, likes,
              apoc.map.fromLists(COLLECT(h.name), COLLECT(DISLIKES.intensity)) AS dislikes
         WITH person,
              [x IN hobbies | COALESCE(likes[x], 0)] AS likes,
              [x IN hobbies | COALESCE(-dislikes[x], 0)] AS dislikes
         WITH COLLECT({person: person, likes:likes, dislikes:dislikes}) AS coll
       UNWIND coll AS left
       UNWIND coll AS right
         WITH left, right
        WHERE ID(left.person) < ID(right.person)
         WITH left.person AS person,
              right.person AS other,
              EXTRACT(x IN apoc.coll.zip(left.likes, right.likes)       | (x[0] + x[1]) / 2) AS avg_like,
              EXTRACT(x IN apoc.coll.zip(left.dislikes, right.dislikes) | (x[0] + x[1]) / 2) AS avg_dislike,
              apoc.algo.euclideanSimilarity(left.likes, right.likes) AS euclidean_like,
              apoc.algo.euclideanSimilarity(left.dislikes, right.dislikes) AS euclidean_dislike
        MERGE (person)-[LIKE:LIKE_SIMILARITY]->(other)
          SET LIKE.euclidean = euclidean_like,
              LIKE.avg = avg_like
        MERGE (person)-[DISLIKE:DISLIKE_SIMILARITY]->(other)
          SET DISLIKE.euclidean = euclidean_dislike,
              DISLIKE.avg = avg_dislike
       RETURN person.name, other.name, LIKE, DISLIKE;

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| person.name | other.name | LIKE                                                                    | DISLIKE                                                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "Jane Doe"  | "Bob Doe"  | [:LIKE_SIMILARITY {euclidean: 0.013910675635706434, avg: [22, 25, 25]}] | [:DISLIKE_SIMILARITY {euclidean: 0.018466972048042936, avg: [0, -17, -20]}] |
| "John Doe"  | "Jane Doe" | [:LIKE_SIMILARITY {euclidean: 0.012824784198464426, avg: [10, 37, 35]}] | [:DISLIKE_SIMILARITY {euclidean: 0.02287281728431341, avg: [-7, 0, -20]}]   |
| "John Doe"  | "Bob Doe"  | [:LIKE_SIMILARITY {euclidean: 0.024026799286343117, avg: [12, 12, 60]}] | [:DISLIKE_SIMILARITY {euclidean: 0.025589279178274353, avg: [-7, -17, 0]}]  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note: I'm not sure if this is a good similarity measure for your use-case, but this at least demonstrates some data transforms possible with cypher+apoc.

Comment: My use-case was more of a personal exercise, and stdob's answer helped me get to where I needed already. But I think your answer still offers a lot in the way of a different approach and some of the more sophisticated algorithms that Apoc can offer. I'll be sure to check it out.